# How to make edges of box the same?

Tags: html, css

I am making a vertical list of links, but I don't want just plain text, I want a background. I have added this, and have set "padding-right" and added 25px. After this, I noticed that the sizes are different depending on text.

I realize that I could just edit it in HTML, but I also want it to change depending on if its being hovered or not.

Also, I tried setting the width, but that did not work.

Thanks in advance.

HTML

```
<ul id="sidelinksleft">
<li><a href="quickstart.html">Quick Start</a></li>
<li><a href="tagsmain.html">Tag Helper</a></li>
<li><a href="html.html">HTML</a></li>
<li><a href="css.html">CSS</a></li>
<li><a href="photoshop.html">Photoshop</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#sidelinksleft{
width:90%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;;
height:25px;
position:relative;
clear: right;
float:left;
}

#sidelinksleft li{
position:relative;
top:2px;
padding-right:20px;
list-style-type: none;
}

#sidelinksleft li a{
color:#777777;
font-size:13px;
font-family: sans-serif;
text-decoration:none;
background-color:#B2FF99;
height:17px;
position:relative;
border:1px solid black;
padding-right:25px;
}

#sidelinksleft li a:hover{
color:#a3a3a3;
font-size:13px;
font-family: sans-serif;
text-decoration:none;
}

#sidelinksleft li a:active{
color:#00B2EE;
font-size:13px;
font-family: sans-serif;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove width:90% from `#sidelinksleft` and then add the following they will end up as the same size:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pD6rR/)

```
#sidelinksleft li a {
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:2px;
}
```

So what this is doing is expanding all `a` elements out to fill 100% of its parent which in turn is width of the largest child.

FYI You need to apply it to the `a` element (not just `li`) if you want the entire area to trigger the link.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, your background color and padding are specified for your `a` elements, which vary in size depending on their contents because they're inline.  This is also why you can't change the width on the anchors - they're inline instead of block.

You'd probably be better off moving your background color and border styles to the `li` elements, and adding a little margin and width to spread them out.  Example:

```
#sidelinksleft li a { /* remove border and bg declarations */ }
#sidelinksleft li {
  background-color:#B2FF99;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 40%;
}
```